# Trouble with Array in C++ header

Tags: c++, arrays

So I'm trying to make a simple little database in C++ for fun.  I want to do it using arrays.  But I keep getting errors though.  I want it to increment integer 'i' after the user enters in the student information. So that way it will allow a Infinite amount of names ages to be entered. And I want to eventually store the names the user enters into a notepad. I could do this in a int main(), but I am trying to experiment with headers.

I am having a lot of trouble with the arrays.

Heres a snippet of code that I am using in the header and the CPP file.  I tried declaring int 'i' in private and int 'b' in public and putting them into the arrays and then pointing the private to the public in the CPP file but it didn't work. 
If you guys could help me that would be great thanks!  BTW I'm new so please forgive my ignorance.  I'm not whether I used the pointers right either.

```
 #include <string>

 class student3
 {
     protected:
     int i;
     std :: string *_studentFirstName[];
     std :: string *_studentLastName[];
     int *_studentAge[];
     double *_studentGPA[];

     public:
      int b;
      void setstudentFirstName(std :: string firstName[]);
      void setstudentLastName(std :: string lastName[]);
      void setstudentAge(int Age[]);
      void setstudentGPA(double GPA[]);
      std :: string getstudentFirstName();
      std :: string getstudentLastName();
      int getstudentAge();
      double getstudentGPA();
  }
```

---

```
#include "student3.h"

void student3 :: setstudentFirstName(std :: string firstName[b])
{
*_studentFirstName[i] = firstName[b];
}
void student3 :: setstudentLastName(std :: string lastName[b])
{
*_studentLastName[i] = lastName[b];
}
void student3 :: setstudentAge(int Age[b])
{
*_studentAge[i] = Age[b];
}
void student3 :: setstudentGPA(double GPA[b])
{
*_studentGPA[i] = GPA[b];
}
std :: string student3 :: getstudentFirstName()
{
 return *_studentFirstName[i];
}
std :: string student3 :: getstudentLastName()
{
 return *_studentLastName[i];
}
int student3 :: getstudentAge()
{
return *_studentAge[i];
}
double student3 :: getstudentGPA()
{
return *_studentGPA[i];
}
```

Comment: Does this actually compile? You're missing a ; at the end of the class declaration, before the #include "student3.h" line

Comment: To start with, I don't think you actually mean to use empty arrays of pointers. To continue, you should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). I think you need to read more about arrays and pointers, what's their similarities are and what their differences are.

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer

Comment: If you're using `c++` you should really be using `std::vector`

Comment: engh still doesnt compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `Student` object represent a single student, then use a `std::vector<Student>` to have a collection of them.

Much simplified example:-

```
class Student
{
 public:
   std :: string firstName;
   std :: string lastName;
   int age;
   double gpa;
} 

std::vector<Student> students;

...
Student temp;
temp.firstName = "Arthur";  // or read from user, of course
temp.lasttName = "Dent";
temp.age = 42;

students.push_back(temp); // adds a *copy* of temp to the vector.
```

Comment: k so I guess Im going to have to do some more reading. Because I have no idea what a vector is. lol

Comment: @Snewman8771 - it's just an array that can grow dynamically. Worry about getting your "Student" object right, then having a collection of them just isn't a problem. Until you understand vectors you could just have `Student students[100];` to get an array of 100 of them. No different, really.

Comment: will the user be able to enter the name of the student?  I dont it to be hard coded

Comment: yea but i want a array that will grow dynamically as the user enters names, ages, ect